# jQuery Slideshow wont fade in and out

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slider

My slider wont fade in since i removed `.end()` cause that give me some problems in the slideshow but how can i make it fade in and out again. It works in the fiddle i made but not on my site. http://jsfiddle.net/HUkBp/2/

my code:

```
 <div id="slideshow">
   <div>
     <img src="imgs/supp1.jpg">
   </div>
   <div>
     <img src="imgs/supp2.jpg">
   </div>
   <div>
     <img src="imgs/supp3.jpg">
   </div>
   <div>
     <img src="imgs/supp4.jpg">
   </div>
   <div>
     <img src="imgs/supp5.jpg">
   </div>
   <div>
     <img src="imgs/supp6.jpg">
   </div>
   <div>
     <img src="imgs/supp8.jpg">
   </div>
   <div>
     <img src="imgs/supp9.jpg">
   </div>
   <div>
     <img src="imgs/supp10.jpg">
   </div>
 </div>
```

CSS:

```
#slideshow { 
    margin: 50px auto; 
    position: relative;   
}

#slideshow > div { 
    position: absolute; 
}
```

jQuery:

```
$("#slideshow > div:gt(0)").hide();

setInterval(function() { 
  $('#slideshow > div:first')
    .fadeOut(1000)
    .next()
    .fadeIn(1000)
    .appendTo('#slideshow');
},  3000);
```

Comment: Did you try without the `.end()` in your `setInterval (...)` ?

Comment: it fixed the slider going back but now the sliders wont fade they just appear but its something haha thanks for that already :D

Comment: [This JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HUkBp/4/) may help you. Try it's js on your website. I just sliced your `setInterval (...)` into 2 parts and removed the `.next()`. I hope it will help you.

Comment: @Rofez it's better to avoid answers in comments because the question will remain unanswered forever (unless the problem was caused by a typographical error and gets closed by community). Please consider adding an answer with some explanation.

Comment: @Tilwin Joy Yeah I know but I have no real explanation for this, so I hope one of you will find why this is not working with my code to post a complete answer with the full explanation.

Comment: Is your code wrapped in `$(document).ready()`? are you sure the code runs after elements are created..? this could be the most obvious reason for code working in fiddle and not in your website. unless you give us link to where it doesn't work, no one can pin point the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't remove `.end()` cause you need the first slide move to end of slideshow. Without `.end()` the second one will be moved. So you had right code:

```
setInterval(function() { 
    $('#slideshow > div:first')
    .fadeOut(1000)
    .next()
    .fadeIn(1000)
    .end()
    .appendTo('#slideshow');
},  3000);
```

Can you give a link to your site where it doesn't work?